# Django website tracked by piwik on same webserver

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, matomo

I'm trying to run a django website which is handled over the mod-wsgi module by an apache2 webserver and to track this site with piwik which is "running" on the same maschine and served by the same apache2 webserver.

Piwik lives under /var/www/piwik/.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@test.com


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /path/to/django/static-files
    <Directory /path/to/django/static-files>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /path/to/django/wsgifile>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess django-cms python-home=/path/to/python/env python-path=/path/to/django-project
    WSGIProcessGroup django-project
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django/wsgifile/wsgi.py

#       DocumentRoot /var/www/piwik
#       <Directory /var/www/piwik>
#               Require all granted
#       </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Later running on port 443 (SSL).

But what do I need to change to access piwik? Use seperate port for it?

Or is is a "bad" practice to run piwik on the same server?

Answer (score 3):

Read this blog post for details on how you can host a PHP application on mod_wsgi at the same time as a Python application.

- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/hosting-php-web-applications-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the manual. It was made for apache 2.2 I guess? Second, do you recommend to run piwik on a separate server?

Comment: So long as you use mod_wsgi daemon mode for the Python application, and make sure you have set ``WSGIRestrictEmbedded On``, which you don't, then one can live with using same Apache for PHP if done for pure convenience. If you have high throughput applications where performance is a concern, host them separately and properly tune the server for each for the specific application.